# Error en método “Cannot asign to ‘’ Because its a ‘Method Group’

Tags: c#, método

Lo qué pasa, es que tengo un error, El evento `Form.Load` no funciona, en la sección de propiedades de `form1`, el evento `Load` está vacío, cuando antes estaba lleno por el texto/evento `Form1_Load`. Al hacer clic en este campo, se crea un nuevo evento `Form1_Load_1`, Pero en la lista de errores marca

> “Cannot asign to ‘Load’ Because its a Method group.”

Este error se marca en el archivo de `Form1 Designer`. Ya he intentado borrar esa línea pero el evento sigue sin realizarse y nuevamente al ver la sección de eventos está vacía. (Y si vuelvo a dar click crea `Form1_Load_2` el cual tampoco funciona y marca el mismo error).
Por su atención, Gracias.
**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
El código del diseñador es :

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.HomeForm_Load_2);
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2 **  El código del diseñador de HomeForm (Form1) Es el siguiente:

```
// 
        // HomeForm
        // 
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1370, 749);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.MuteIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SoundIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ErrorNoFilesLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.FileLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.GarbageIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SelectIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.OpenIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.NewIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.HomeTitle);
        this.Controls.Add(this.FileDock);
        this.Controls.Add(this.FileLabelDock);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SettingsIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.AnalyticsIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SelectedHome);
        this.Controls.Add(this.MenuDock);
        this.Controls.Add(this.HelpIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SearchButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.FilterIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SearchPic);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SearchBar);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SearchBarIcon);
        this.Controls.Add(this.MenuLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.MenuLabelBack);
        this.Controls.Add(this.TopBar);
        this.Controls.Add(this.HomeBoard);
        this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 200);
        this.Name = "HomeForm";
        this.Text = "Home";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.HomeForm_Load_2);
        this.LocationChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.HomeForm_LocationChanged);
        this.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.HomeForm_TextChanged);
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.HomeForm_KeyDown);
        this.Validated += new System.EventHandler(this.HomeForm_Validated);
        this.NewContextMenu.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.HomeBoardMenu.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SelectIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.OpenIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.NewIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SettingsIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.AnalyticsIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SelectedHome)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.HelpIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SearchButton)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.FilterIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.MuteIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SoundIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.GarbageIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.FileDock)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.FileLabelDock)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.MenuDock)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SearchPic)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.SearchBarIcon)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.MenuLabelBack)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.TopBar)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.HomeBoard)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
```

Algo muy curioso, es que al momento de entrar al archivo HomeForm.cs [Design] (No confundir con HomeForm.Desginer.cs, me muestra este otro error, provocado supongo por el evento.

[image: Este es el error al momento de entrar al Diseñador de manera visual de HomeForm]

Comment: Has intentado crear manualmente el método form1_Loaf

Comment: Interesante.. podrias mostrar la seccion de codigo del designer que esta fallando?

Comment: ¿Cómo creo el método manualmente?

Comment: Sin ver código es un poco dificil que te ayudemos. Copianos al menos la linea en la que te da el error

Comment: Hola, el archivo que necesitamos ver es  el `Form1.Designer.cs`. gracias

Comment: Estas asignando el metodo Load asi `Load = (source, e) =>{ ... }` cuando deberia de ser `Load += (source, e) =>{ ... }` pero si publicaras tu codigo donde esta el error, seria mucho mejor.

Comment: Ese código parece correcto, asi que puede ser algun bug del Visual Studio.Intenta cambiar el framework de destino a otro diferente,y luego vuelves al que tienes a ver si asi te funciona

Answer (score -1):

revisa el método `InitializeComponent` en tu archivo `Form1.Designer.cs`. Seguramente te esté ocurriendo esto

```
this.Form_Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form_Load);
```

Se debería cambiar a los siguiente

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form_Load); // como ves se asigna el manejador this.Form_Load al evento Load del formulario
```

Comment: Estás seguro de esto? No sería mejor esperar a que el OP mostrara lo que tiene en su designer para responder?

Comment: No creo que sea eso, mas que nada porque dice que "en la sección de propiedades de form1, el evento Load está vacío", por lo que el diseñador no va a poner algo que no es un evento. Mas bien yo creo que es un bug que me ha pasado, en donde le das doble click a un control para asignar el evento y no lo hace, eso o algo tiene en el método, quizás tiene creado un método que sellama igual al evento y el diseñador intenta crearlo.

Comment: Mi código está justo igual que la segunda opción, Pero el problema está justo ahí, en la parte de **this.Load** += new System.EventHandler(this.HomeForm_Load_2);

Comment: Puedes poner el código completo en tu pregunta?

Comment: Ok, Permiteme un segundo

Comment: Listo, ya la he actualizado.

Comment: Hola, has probado en borrar esta línea `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.HomeForm_Load_2);` ? Existe el manejador `HomeForm_Load_2`del evento `Load` en tu clase? También te recomendaría buscar en esa clase todas las referencias a `Load` y al menos comentar esas lineas. Puedes situarte en el archivo `HomeForm.cs `, pulsar el botón derecho del ratón y seleccionar `View Code`

Comment: Sergio, si no mecionas al OP con @, no le llegará notificación de tu comentario

Comment: Gracias, @LinkSeb puedes echar un vistazo a mi comentario? Gracias